# Why are the options Sharing and Remote Desktop always on between restarts on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: remote-desktop, sharing

I use GNOME 42 on Ubuntu 22.04. I was checking for open ports on my network and noticed that port 3389 (RDP) is open. I disable it through the gui. When I restart this port opens again. Why?

[image: sharing options on]

Comment: How did you disable the port? Did you use some command, or clicked on the On/Off button as shown on your picture above? Did you change the **Remote Desktop** from On to Off or Turned off the blue button to the right of **Sharing** at the top?

Comment: Clicked off from the GUI.

Comment: It may be a bug. You should [create a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en). Bugs are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

It can be disabled permanently by `uninstall gnome-remote-desktop`,

```
sudo apt remove gnome-remote-desktop
sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove
```

I finally get rid of it.

Comment: Do remember to reboot your device.